# Making MVC5 Html.DropDownlistFor() work on post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am not understanding why the ModelState is invalid on post for the following code and what to do about it.

My initial Action:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        InstitutionManager im = new InstitutionManager();
        im.AddressTypeList = new SelectList(db.AddressTypes.Where(a => a.Active).ToList(), "Id", "Name");          
        return View(im);
    }
```

My post action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(InstitutionManager im)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Institution inst = new Institution();
           //Bunch of code here to save changes
            db.Institutions.Add(inst);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }           
        return View(im);
    }
```

The portion of my view that is causing the issue:

```
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressTypeList, "Address Type", new { @class = "control-label ddlLabel sr-only" })
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AddressTypeId, Model.AddressTypeList, "--Address Type--", new { @class = "form-control floatLabel ", placeholder = "Address Type" })
```

My View Model:

```
 public class InstitutionManager
{
    [Display(Name = "Institution Name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address 1")]
    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public SelectList AddressTypeList { get; set; }
    public string AddressTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? Id { get; set; }
//Other stuff removed to simplify
}
```

This works fine and populates the dropdown lists accordingly. But when I post the form the ModelState is invalid. I assume it's because the SelectList is now empty, but what is the correct way deal with the select lists? I could use Viewbag but I would really like to keep everything in the viewmodel.

Comment: You say you "assume it's because the SelectList is now empty" but I can't see why that would make the model invalid and more to the point, what is the actual validation error?

Comment: The `SelectList` has nothing to do with your model being invalid. Inspect `ModelState.Errors` to determine which property is invalid.